# Query in Ms Access, how to make a chain of joins (with its own criteria) that only show up if the first part of the join exists

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to make a query that makes a new table from 7 different tables, and then I need to use this query in a C# program, so I wouldn't be able to make 2 queries to do this.

How would I make a join that only shows up if the two parts of the join are equal, and if it does show up, it gets more info from a third table and only really shows up if one of its columns in the third table equals 2.

For example, I have a lot of different joins, and at one part, Table 1, I join it to Table 2. I want everything from table 1 to show up, and only the matching ones from table 2. and if table 1 and 2 match, the info in table 2 only shows up if it fits a certain criteria from table 3, which is join to table 2.

I hope that makes sense?

Thanks!

EDIT

okay the main problem is am I able to set criteria that only happens for a certain join and not the whole query?

Comment: You can use an Inner Join

Comment: i tried that, but how do i set the criteria so it only applies when it reaches that part of the join?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're going to have to post the details of what is not working for you, the code as written and some example data.

Comment: instead of seeking a quick fix which in your case will not help because you have not displayed any code in regards to what you have already tried as well as where you have run into a road block.. here is a great place to start I would do tons of googling on how to write Joins in SQL [MSDN How to Perform Joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb243855%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Its "join", not "joint"

Answer (score 0):

From the info you have provided it sounds like you want to left join table 2 to table 1, and inner join table 3 to table 2, using your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

**for example, i have alot of different joints, and at one part, Table 1, i join it to Table 2.**

Ok, you want Table 1 to join to Table 2.

**I want everything from table 1 to show up, and only the matching ones from table 2.**

This is called a Left Join from Table1 to Table2. A Left Join returns all records from the left hand table, even if there is no matching record in the right hand table.

So, so far we have

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
```

**and if table 1 and 2 match, the info in table 2 only shows up if it fits a certain criteria from table 3, which is joint to table 2.**

This means you want an inner join between Table2 and Table3. An Inner Join returns all records that match both the left and right hand tables. Let's combine this with our first query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.ID = T2.ID
```

*However, this won't work.* This only returns records that match all 3 tables because the Inner Join is applied to the result from the first Left Join.
What you need in this circumstance is a derived table. You can get one by using the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM @Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T2.ID as T2ID, T2.HairColor as HairColor, T3.ID as T3ID, T3.Age as Age FROM @Table2 T2
    INNER JOIN @Table3 T3 ON T3.ID = T2.ID
    WHERE T3.Age = 3
    ) as T2SubSet ON t1.ID = T2SubSet.T2ID
```

This is evaluated by creating the subset of table 2/3 that you are looking for and then taking the result of that query and joining it to table 1 with a left join. For a full complete example, you can use the following query:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(
ID int,
Name varchar(10))

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(
ID int,
HairColor varchar(10))

DECLARE @Table3 TABLE(
ID int,
Age int)


INSERT INTO @Table1 values (1, 'John'), (2, 'Mary'), (3,'Sue')
INSERT INTO @Table2 values (1, 'Red'), (2, 'Brown'), (3, 'Black')
INSERT INTO @Table3 values (1, 3), (2, 5), (4,8)

SELECT *
FROM @Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN @Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
    INNER JOIN @Table3 T3 ON T3.ID = T2.ID


SELECT *
FROM Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T2.ID as T2ID, T2.HairColor as HairColor, T3.ID as T3ID, T3.Age as Age FROM Table2 T2
    INNER JOIN Table3 T3 ON T3.ID = T2.ID
    ) as T2SubSet ON t1.ID = T2SubSet.T2ID
```

I also just noticed you said:
 **columns in the third table equals 2.**

This can be done by adding another 'On' statement like 'T3.Column = 2' Using my last query above, it would be

```
SELECT *
FROM @Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT T2.ID as T2ID, T2.HairColor as HairColor, T3.ID as T3ID, T3.Age as Age FROM @Table2 T2
    INNER JOIN @Table3 T3 ON T3.ID = T2.ID AND T3.Age = 2
    ) as T2SubSet ON t1.ID = T2SubSet.T2ID
```